# Exceeding request quotas

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I am using Google map in my website, it gives this error:

> This page can't load Google Maps correctly

Also it shows this in the console:

> You have exceeded your request quota for this API. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/

[image]

I have enabled the billing, checked the Quotas none of my quotas currently have usage. I have enabled this service Geocoding API, Geolocation API, Maps JavaScript API, and I also have a valid API key.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might be doing something wrong in how you are including your key.  What does the javascript console tell you?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, and provide the error messages from the javascript console.

Answer (score 0):

The error might occur if you changed your QPS (Quota Per Second) less than 100.